# Linear multivariable system subject to bounded disturbance

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

There is this topic "Linear Control Systems" with vast literature. Nevertheless, I am still able to make further thoughts to bring some new ideas to it. For instance:

Given the time derivative $\dot{x}$ equal to vector span $A x + B u + d$, for bounded disturbance $\lvert\lvert d \rvert\rvert \leq \delta$, provide a control map $K \, x + \nu$ such that state timeseries $\lvert\lvert x(t) \rvert\rvert \leq \varepsilon$ for time $t \to \infty$ hold.

I know, the linear control map $K x$ with such eigenvalues $\lambda(A+BK) \in \mathbb{C}^-$ guarantee this condition asymptotically. However, I fail to find control map candidates $\nu$ to supress disturbances.

Any control map $\nu$ that satisfies the inequality below is valid:

$$\varepsilon > \exp((A+BK)t) + \int\limits_0^t \exp((A+BK)\tau) (d(\tau) + B \nu(t)) d\tau$$

Comment: This question needs more precision. Is it to suppress the disturbance asymptotically? Is it "for any $\delta$ there exists an $\epsilon$ and $K, \nu$ so that" or is it "for all $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ there exists a $K, \nu$ so that". I assume its asymptotic rejection but just want to confirm.

Comment: What specific type of disturbance are you considering? Because there are methods for dealing with certain types of disturbances, such as exogenous disturbances for ones that can be modeled, another method that comes to mind is sliding mode control. But without knowing what exact disturbance you are considering, it is hard find the appropriate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so from my understanding, you would like to have

$$
\limsup_{t\to\infty}||x(t)||\le\epsilon
$$
and assume that $\epsilon$ is left free, that is, we would like to find a suitable expression for it.

Let us also assume that $d$ is a constant. Then, we get that

$$
||x(t)||\le \int_0^t||e^{(A+BK)(t-s)}(d+B\nu)||\mathrm{d}s\le M\dfrac{1-e^{-\alpha t}}{\alpha}||d+B\nu||\le \dfrac{M}{\alpha}||d+B\nu||
$$

where $M\ge1,\alpha>0$ are such that

$$
||e^{(A+BK)t}||\le Me^{-\alpha t},\ t\ge0.
$$

Those constant can be computed by solving the Lyapunov inequality

$$(A+BK)^TP+P(A+BK)\preceq-2\alpha P$$

in $P\succ0$ and $M$ will be given by $(\lambda_{\max}(P)/\lambda_{\min}(P))^{1/2}$ where $\lambda_{\max}(P)$ and $\lambda_{\min}(P)$ are the maximum and minimum eigenvalue of $P$, respectively.

Since the terms $M/\alpha$ and $||d+B\nu||$ are independent, and only the latter depends on $\nu$. Let us just focus on this one.

So, in the end, what we would like is to find $\nu$ that solves

$$
\min_\nu\max_{||d||\le\delta}||d+B\nu||.
$$

Assuming that $B$ is full-column rank, it can be shown that the optimal value is $\nu^*=0$. This makes sense since it is a neutral value that may not add to the value for $d$.

As a result, since the disturbance $d$ is not known, it is not possible to "suppress" it using $\nu$. The only thing that can be done is to attenuate it, that is having a ratio $M/\alpha$ as small as possible. You may check the literature on the $L_\infty$-gain and the $L_1$-control, which addresses such a problem.

Comment: May you clarify what do constants $M$ and $\alpha$ stand for in this context?

Comment: I have edited my answer.